# Clarification about Poisson summation formula

Tags: complex-analysis, fourier-analysis, fourier-series, poisson-summation-formula

I'm almost sure that I haven't understood correctly the Poisson formula

$$\sum_{n=-\infty}^{+\infty}f(t-nT)=\frac{1}{T}\sum_{m=-\infty}^{+\infty}F\left(\frac{2\pi m}{T}\right) e^{\frac {-i2\pi m t}{T}}.$$

If I try to apply it to the shifted delta, I get:

$$\sum_{n=-\infty}^{+\infty}\delta(t-nT)=\frac{1}{T} \sum_{m=-\infty}^{+\infty} 
e^{\frac {-i2\pi m (nT)}{T}}e^{\frac {-i2\pi m t}{T}}$$

but I have obtained two different indices (m and n) in the same sum.... (right hand of expression)

The correct answer - if I'm not wrong - should be 
$$\sum_{n=-\infty}^{+\infty}\delta(t-nT)=\frac{1}{T} \sum_{m=-\infty}^{+\infty} e^{\frac {-i2\pi m t}{T}}$$

Thanks  for your help

Comment: The Poisson summation formula is that **if both side converge uniformly** then $\sum_{n=-\infty}^{+\infty}f(t-nT)=\frac{1}{T}\sum_{m=-\infty}^{+\infty}F(\frac{2\pi m}{T}) e^{\frac {-i2\pi m t}{T}}$. And $e^{-2i \pi mn T/T} = 1$. Also $$\sum_{n=-\infty}^{+\infty}\delta(t-nT)=\frac{1}{T} \sum_{m=-\infty}^{+\infty} e^{\frac {-i2\pi m t}{T}}$$ is true only **in the sense of distributions** (in this sense, the Poisson summation formula just becomes the convolution theorem together with $\sum_n \delta(t-n)$ being its own Fourier transform)

Comment: As @user1952009 says, Poisson summation formula is easily understandable by directly using convolution/product by "Dirac comb" $\sum_n \delta(t-n).$

Comment: @user1952009 I'm sorry but I haven't understood... If I write the Poisson summation formula I'm implicitly assuming that $e^{\frac {-i2\pi m (nT)}{T}}=1$? Are the steps that I have followed correct?

Comment: $m,n$ are integers so $e^{-2i \pi m (nT)/T} = e^{-2i \pi mn} = 1$. You didn't follow any steps. $\delta(t)$ is a distribution and $\sum_n \delta(t-nT)$ doesn't converge, so the Poisson summation doesn't apply (even if it stays true **in the sense of distributions**)

Comment: @user1952009 Thanks for your kindness. This topic was exposed very quickly during the class.. How can I understand if both sides converge uniformly? When, for sure, I can't apply the formula? Which are the 'warnings'? many thanks again

Comment: Try to see why it works well for $f(t) =F(t) = e^{-\pi t^2}$ (in this case $f $ is a Schwartz function)

Comment: @user1952009 because it is continuos and derivable with continuity?

Comment: Let $f(t) = e^{-\pi t^2}$ and $g(t) = \sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty f(t-n)$, it is $1$-periodic. What are its Fourier series coefficients, and what is its Fourier series, does it converge ? @JeanMarie

Comment: It is a Jacobi $\theta$ function (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theta_function)